# How can an item that everybody gets every game doesn't have a 50% win rate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was browsing the statistics on LoLKing and found something odd.

http://www.lolking.net/charts?region=all&type=item-popularity&range=monthly&map=ha&queue=normal

On Howling Abyss (ARAM map), the Cookie, given to every player at the beginning of the game, is not exactly 50% win/loss. (We are talking about 50.15%)

How could this happen? How can an item that everybody (event the afks) gets every game doesn't have a 50% win rate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The champion Rengar does not receive the Poro Snax, instead he has his bonetooth necklace trinket. This would explain the small gap in wins-loses.

Comment: confirmed: http://www.lolking.net/champions/rengar&region=all&map=ha&queue=normal#statistics

Answer (score 0):

That stats are based on game ending items. Not everyone ends the game with the cookie, as some people feed it to Poros.
Conclusion: Don't feed the Poro and your odds at winning increases.

Answer (score -3):

Your premise is flawed, the cookie is not given to every player, it is acquired by players with  a certain mastery. The higher win rate, in this context, indicates that the mastery is probably slightly better than average.

Comment: Actually he is not talking about the Biscuit from masteries, it's the Poro-Snax which is given at the beginning of every ARAM game regardless of masteries.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense